# how to create form validation in classic asp?

Tags: validation, asp-classic

I am newbie in classic asp. I have created simple login form which includes only username and password.

Here is my logon.asp:

```
<%
Username="Administrator"
Password="Admin"
Validated = "OK"
if Strcomp(Request.Form("User"),Username,1)=0 AND Request.Form("password") = Password then
'Set the validation cookie and redirect the user to the original page.
    Response.Cookies("ValidUser") = Validated
    'Check where the users are coming from within the application.
    If (Request.QueryString("from")<>"") then
    Response.Redirect Request.QueryString("from")
    else
    'If the first page that the user accessed is the Logon page,
        'direct them to the default page.
          Response.Redirect "MyPage.asp"
    End if    
Else
' Only present the failure message if the user typed in something.
    If Request.Form("User") <> "" then
        Response.Write "<h3>Authorization Failed.</h3>" & "<br>" & _
        "Please try again.<br>&#xa0;<br>"
    End if
End if
%>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<FORM ACTION=<%Response.Write "Logon.asp?"&Request.QueryString%> method="post">
<p> 
Username: 
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="User" VALUE='' size="20"></INPUT> <br />
Password: 
<INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="password" VALUE='' size="20"></INPUT>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Logon"></INPUT>
</FORM>
```

This is mypage.asp:

```
<%
Validated = "OK"
if Request.Cookies("ValidUser") <> Validated then
'Construct the URL for the current page.
    dim s
    s = "http://"
    s = s & Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")
    s = s & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
    if Request.QueryString.Count > 0 THEN
    s = s & "?" & Request.QueryString 
    end if
    'Redirect unauthorized users to the logon page.
    Response.Redirect "Logon.asp?from=" &Server.URLEncode(s)
End if
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Protected Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p align="center">This is my secret information<br>
You cannot see it unless you<br>
are properly logged on!</p>
```

When i enter the logon button without fill the input fields, it shows like this "username or password required". May i know, how to create validation code, and how to add code in my existing code?

Any asp expert can guide me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add one more condition in your logon.asp page:

```
    <%
    Username="Administrator"
    Password="Admin"
    Validated = "OK"
If Trim(Request.Form("User")) <> "" And Trim(Request.Form("password")) <> "" Then
    if Strcomp(Request.Form("User"),Username,1)=0 AND Request.Form("password") = Password then
    'Set the validation cookie and redirect the user to the original page.
        Response.Cookies("ValidUser") = Validated
        'Check where the users are coming from within the application.
        If (Request.QueryString("from")<>"") then
        Response.Redirect Request.QueryString("from")
        else
        'If the first page that the user accessed is the Logon page,
            'direct them to the default page.
              Response.Redirect "MyPage.asp"
        End if    
    Else
    ' Only present the failure message if the user typed in something.
        If Request.Form("User") <> "" then
            Response.Write "<h3>Authorization Failed.</h3>" & "<br>" & _
            "Please try again.<br>&#xa0;<br>"
        End if
    End if
End If
    %>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <FORM ACTION=<%Response.Write "Logon.asp?"&Request.QueryString%> method="post">
    <p> 
    Username: 
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="User" VALUE='' size="20"></INPUT> <br />
    Password: 
    <INPUT TYPE="password" NAME="password" VALUE='' size="20"></INPUT>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Logon"></INPUT>
    </FORM>
```

Hope this would help. Thank you.